# 2005 Chevrolet 2500hd, SRS light stays on after replacing air bags

Tags: chevrolet, silverado

I T-boned a Dodge at 45 ended up with no frame damage. Had all the proper pieces replaced. How do I get the SRS light in the dash to turn off? Is this something I have to go to the dealer?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you know what the codes are for the SRS?

Comment: Also, there are *two* SRS sensors (at least) up front which sit under the core support ... did you replace both of these? All wiring good to these as well?

Comment: I believe it something like deploy comand

Comment: Four codes B0051(1/4) Current Deployment Commanded. B0103 (2/4) current Front impact Sensor 2 Performance.  B0051 (3/4) History Deployment Commanded.  B0103 (4/4) History Front Impact Sensor 2 Performance.

Comment: My SRS reader will clear the codes set, so if you can get them read, you should be able to clear them ... It looks like front impact sensor two needs to be changed out. There are two of these sensors which mount to the bottom of the core support. I don't know which is #1 and which is #2. When I changed them out on my '06 Silvy when one went bad, I changed both of them. You might be able to find them at a Pick-A-Part yard, but who knows if they will be any good. Anyway, this is an educated guess, but you'll still need to clear the codes after the sensor is swapped out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need a tech 2 clone.  There's a module for the BCM you need to go to.  The cheapest clone is the [vxnano](http://www.vxdiagshop.com/wholesale/vxdiag-vcx-nano-for-gm-opel.html) for GM cars.  But, unless you are super poor, don't buy it.  Just drive to the dealer and pay them to do it, because installing the software for a vxnano and getting it to work could take a few days.